# How to delete amazon s3 object from flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, amazon-s3

according to Amazon S3 REST API deleting an object requires a DELETE request, like

```
DELETE /myobject.txt
Host: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
...
Authorization: <auth>
```

But the URLRequest.method field in Flash can be set only to GET or POST, so I cannot create such a request. Any idea?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea unless you either want to make all those files available for deletion by anyone, or have your private secret key in your public flash file (easily findable with a decompiler or even a hex editor).

Comment: In addition to what @JonatanHedborg said, you may also encounter problems when including Authorization in your header. More info here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/authorization-header-request-flash-player.html The best approach is probably to communicate with an intermediate server-side service.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible to make a POST request to your server and then make a DELETE request from  let's say php to amazon?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [as3httpclient](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient) lib, it makes DELETE requests available